# The meaning of "adequacy" in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I want to know the meaning of "adequacy" in this sentence.

"Perfection in tasks where adequacy would do.avoid!"

What's the exact meaning of second part of the sentence?

Comment: Where is the sentence from? It is an incomplete sentence and does not seem to mean very much.

Comment: Yes, it's not a complete sentence. It's from a book and it's one of the listed works that wastes our time.

Comment: Are there actually two sentences with poor punctuation? Perhaps it means that the situation where one tries to complete a task *perfectly* should be avoided, when it would be good enough to complete the task *adequately*. For example, sharpening a pencil so that exactly the same amount of wood is on all sides of the lead, would be overly perfect, even obsessive behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the full quotation is something like this:

> Things that waste your time:
>
> - Perfection in tasks where adequacy would do. Avoid!

I believe this sentence means the same as your quotation, and is easier to understand:

> Avoid perfection in tasks where adequacy would do.

['Adequacy'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adequacy) here means that the task has been done well enough to meet a certain requirement. Adequacy in this context is the state of something that is [adequate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adequate), just as perfection is the state of something that is perfect.

The overall sentence means that there are some tasks where one should not do more than is needed to complete the task. An example might be building a temporary structure - if it is safe, then it is a waste of time to try to make it beautiful.